# PNDate return nil in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, pubnub

I use
`PubNub.requestFullHistoryForChannel(channel  , includingTimeToken: true , withCompletionBlock: { messages , channel , startDate , endDate , error in
           let dic =  messages[0].message as Dictionary<String , String>
             let date = messages[0].date as PNDate! })`
to fetch the history messages 
when i use println() to show the messages **date : PNDate ** is not nil

```
 "PNMessage (0x7fcb69d252c0): <message: {\n    text = yup;\n    type = fromUser;\n}, date: PNDate (0x7fcb69d25300) <date: 2015-02-17 12:21:31 +0000; time token: 14241756912535903>, channel: Hazem>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the time of sent message from

```
let date = messages[i].receiveDate  as PNDate
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @ Simon W sorry but i can not make my answer as right answer until tomorrow :)